# windows 7 dbc connection sqlanywhere 11

Tags: odbc, sqlanywhere, administrator

I'm trying to connect from my ms windows 7 via the odbc administrator to a remote
sybase sqlanywhere 11 database server.

But I get not connection, I'm not sure which configure option I have to specify.

server-name = ip address of remote database server?

startline ?

portnummer ?

Thank you, best regards, Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the SQL Anywhere server process `dbsrv#.exe` listens for incoming connections on port 2638.

Make sure your firewall allows outbound connections to that port.

Assuming you have a database running on your server as follows:

```
-x tcpip
-n my_server_name
"[DIR]\database_main_file.db" -n my_database_name
```

The server will broadcast on the tcp/ip layer on the default port (2638) under the name "my_server_name" and the database will be accessible under the name "my_database_name" via ODBC

Creating an ODBC entry for your new database to connect from a client (adjust for Windows 7)

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\myodbcentry]
"Driver"="C:\\PROGRA~1\\SQLANY~1\\Bin32\\dbodbc11.dll"
"DatabaseName"="my_database_name"
"ServerName"="my_server_name"
"LINKS"="TCPIP(IP=SERVER_IP_ADDRESS;PORT=2638)"
```

There are other parameters available for LINKS (HOST, etc). Take a look at http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1101en/dbadmin_en11/da-using-tcpip.html

I've seen some rare issues with UDP broadcast packets. See the docs at 
http://dcx.sybase.com/1101en/dbadmin_en11/broadcastlistener-connection-conparm.html and check with your network administrator.

You can also use the `dbping.exe` utility to troubleshoot networking issues.

BTW, you may want to cross-post your question at http://sqla.stackexchange.com. It's full of SQL Anywhere buffs